# table is creating 1 row instead of creating 9 rows

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have 67 categories in my db, i call the categories using `$categories`.

I would like to print them all out into a table dynamically.

What i have tried so far:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php
            $countCat  = round(count($categories) / 10); // 67 / 10 = 6. 7 | with round = 7
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($categories as $key => $value) { 
                ++$i;
                if ($i >= 10) {

        ?>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>">
          <input type="checkbox" id="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"><?php print $value['categoryNames']; ?></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <?php
      }
      if ($i >= 20) { ?>

      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>">
          <input type="checkbox" id="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
          <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"><?php print $value['categoryNames']; ?></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      </tr>
        <?php

      }
        } 
      ?>

  </tbody>
```

Result:
[image: Result]

it outputs only 1 row even when using $i to stop and create the next row ?

I would like the table to have 9 rows and it should automatically calculate how many columns must be made if there are 67 categories or more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing <tr></tr> tag for rows?

Comment: Tried that an it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 2:

Calculate how many columns u need with `$countCat = ceil(count($categories) / 9);`. => N

Add `</tr><tr>` tags every N items inside the loop to create new row in html table. You can archive this for example with modulo N (% N) for every N items.

`++$i` is moved to the bottom of the loop, to increment at the end.

To ignore creation of `</tr><tr>` in first loop u can use:  `&& $i !== 0`

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $countCat = ceil(count($categories) / 9);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {

            ?>

            <?php if ($i % $countCat === 0 && $i !== 0) { ?></tr><tr><?php } ?>

            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
                <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"><?php print $value['categoryNames']; ?></span>
                </label>
            </td>


            <?php
            ++$i;
        }

        ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hmm what do you want exactly? 10 cells in one row, and then the next 10 cells  in next row? can you update your question above with more details? :)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Wait i change my answer again, didnt read that u want 9 rows constantly.

Comment: Updated my answer (Update 2).